# Jenkins cloud : Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, jenkins

I have this code to run a simple automated test :

```
class AddToCartTest(unittest.TestCase):
direct = os.getcwd()
def setUp(self):
    if os.getenv('CHROMEWEBDRIVER'):
        chromewebdriverbin = os.getenv('CHROMEWEBDRIVER')
    else:
        chromewebdriverbin = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromewebdriverbin)
def test_add_to_cart_with_login(self):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

i have this config on Jenkins shell on my kenkins cloud :

```
export https_proxy=http://proxy.org:3128
export http_proxy=http://proxy.org:3128
```

And i import venv
python3 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
I install PIP and Selenium and Allure report

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install selenium
pip3 install allure-pytest
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
echo "Import chromedriver on the env variable."
export CHROMEWEBDRIVER=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
echo "Import python path on the env variable."
export PYTHONPATH=.
python3 com/POMProject/Tests/Cart/test.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it by updating chromedriver on jenkins who used old version